# Navigation text indent on second line of text

Tags: css

I need to indent the second row of text on this dropdown navigation menu. The issue is that I usually do it with a combination of padding and negative `text-ident` value. But this menu uses the padding for the color on the left. I need to keep all of this styling and look, but need text indent. There is a sample longer row under the "Home" button.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/VZ7qD/20/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Trevor

```
.nav li > ul > li {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background: #0f2992;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: #0f2992 solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.nav li > ul > li > a{
    padding:5px 3px 5px 10px;
    text-indent:-7px;
}
```

Comment: you should use this styles for <a>, not for <li>

Answer (score 0):

or just throw a class on all indented ul's

```
#navMenu ul.indentedNav {margin-left:20px;}
```